# Extract multiple JsonPath values from returned Response using Rest Assured

Tags: rest-assured, jsonpath

I need to obtain two values from JSON response data returned from a Rest Assured modelled request:

Request

```
    public void getCustomerStatuses() {

        Response response =

        given().header("X-AC-User-ID","test-user").
                spec(customerApiSpec).
        when().
                get("/api/v6/status/" + ref + "/").
        then().
                assertThat().statusCode(200).extract().jsonPath();

       String customerStatus =jsonPath.getString("$.cust[?(@.name=='STATUS_ID')].id");

    }
```

Response:

```
{
"count": 4,
"cust": [
    {
        "id": "029384",
        "type": "STATUS",
        "name": "STATUS_ID"
     
    },
    {
        "id": "938736",
        "type": "RENEWAL",
        "name": "RENEWAL_ID"

    }
]
}
```

This throws and `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:Script1.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: '$.cust[?' @ line 1, column 36. $.cust[?(@.name=='STATUS_ID')].id`

What is the correct, best way of obtaining these?  I'm aware I can chain `extract().response().jsonPath();` off the request but not sure how I can obtain >1 value

Comment: could you add sample response

Comment: @PDHide yes that would've been helpful! now done, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsonPath that is used in RestAssured uses the [different syntax](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/json-path/latest/io/restassured/path/json/JsonPath.html). Your path would look like `cust.findAll{i -> i.name == 'STATUS_ID' || i.name == 'RENEWAL_ID'}.id`. Here is the example code:

```java
package click.webelement.api.restassured;

import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import java.util.List;

public class ExtractList {

    static final String JSON = "{\n" +
            "\"count\": 4,\n" +
            "\"cust\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"id\": \"029384\",\n" +
            "        \"type\": \"STATUS\",\n" +
            "        \"name\": \"STATUS_ID\"\n" +
            "     \n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"id\": \"938736\",\n" +
            "        \"type\": \"RENEWAL\",\n" +
            "        \"name\": \"RENEWAL_ID\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "]\n" +
            "}";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(JSON);
        List<String> results = jsonPath.getList("cust.findAll{i -> i.name == 'STATUS_ID' || i.name == 'RENEWAL_ID'}.id");
        for(String result: results){
            System.out.println(result);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: that would explain it, thank you.  I can extract the Response Body as a JsonPath object as the amended question shows, but this throws a `Failed to parse the JSON document` error

Comment: I think changing the question after the answer has been given is a bad idea. You change only your code but rest of your question remains inconsistent. I would revert your changes back and raise new question.

Comment: BTW what does `String.valueOf(response)` return?

Comment: @ Alexey R.
Fair point, not a great idea.  
The return value of `String.valueOf(response)` is just a Json Object `io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath@3d0035d2`

Comment: Ah, I have it.  Thank you for your help, much appreciated